# How to find all contents with modified date of the directory in Objective C code

Tags: objective-c, nsfilemanager

This requirement is very specific to read directory contents along with date modified for all sub files and folders. In windows we have some API's but I didn't find similar function in Mac OS development. I searched for this where I found that NSFileManager can be used for this.I found one place where I can get the path contents under Documents directory.

Here is the piece of code code which I have.

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

NSFileManager *manager = [[NSFileManager alloc] init];
NSDirectoryEnumerator *fileEnumerator = [manager enumeratorAtPath:documentsPath];

for (NSString *filename in fileEnumerator) {
    // Do something with file
    NSLog(@"file name : %@",filename );
}
```

But my requirement is to find the contents under any path on machine with the date modified for all sub files and a folders in it.Please guide me on it.

Thanks,
Tausif.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple has a [code sample](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGUide/AccessingFilesandDirectories/AccessingFilesandDirectories.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010672-CH3-SW5) demonstrating how to do this:

```
NSDirectoryEnumerator *directoryEnumerator = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] enumeratorAtPath:directoryPath];

NSDate *yesterday = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:(-60*60*24)];

for (NSString *path in directoryEnumerator) {

    if ([[path pathExtension] isEqualToString:@"rtfd"]) {
        // Don't enumerate this directory.
        [directoryEnumerator skipDescendents];
    } else {
        NSDictionary *attributes = [directoryEnumerator fileAttributes];
        NSDate *lastModificationDate = [attributes objectForKey:NSFileModificationDate];

        if ([yesterday earlierDate:lastModificationDate] == yesterday) {
            NSLog(@"%@ was modified within the last 24 hours", path);
        }
    }
}
```

Basically this code enumerates the `directoryPath` and checks if the file or directory has been modified within the last 24 hours.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `[NSFilemanager.defaultManager subpathsAtPath:<yourpath> error:nil]` for this. Note that you probably don't want a special NSFileManager instance, so you should use `defaultManager`.

```
NSDate *yesterday = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:(-60*60*24)];

NSFileManager *fm = NSFileManager.defaultManager;
NSArray *subPaths = [fm subpathsAtPath:documentsPath];

for (NSString *path in subPaths) {
    NSDictionary *attributes = [fm fileAttributesAtPath:path traverseLink:YES];
    NSDate *lastModificationDate = [attributes objectForKey:NSFileModificationDate];

    if ([yesterday earlierDate:lastModificationDate] == yesterday) {
        NSLog(@"%@ was modified within the last 24 hours", path);
    }
}
```